# jboss eap 7.0.4 domain authentication error to java connection over http

Tags: java, jboss

we switched from standalone to domain mode, but till then our application can´t connect anymore to the jboss controller trough http://hostname:8080, but with standalone this works!

Is there any hind, where I can look to check this on domain mode?

We get an error that authentication failed, but there is no authentication configured.

just changed from standalone to domain mode.

PRDhost runs the domain controller and a jboss instance.
DEV host runs two jboss instances (dev and test).
All off them are configured to connect to PRD DC.

Which information do you need to give me maybe the hind I need to fix that.

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

Check if port-offset set to server of domain mode you are using. Check port 8080 is opened or not.